# Linking Teams with Communication Site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I have one communication site in production. I want to integrate Teams with the communication site. In short, I should be able to create a teams channel which will point to that communication site. And I don't want to convert communication site into team site as it is live now.

Example : Here is the communication site I have created "MyTestSite" and created one teams channel with same name but under "files" its showing SharePoint site as "MyTestSite2". Because it is a communication site.

[image]

So basically, I want something where I can use one communication site in teams files and main SharePoint site. 
Is there any way to link teams channel with communication site ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this workaround from [Microsoft Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/916352/linking-teams-with-communication-site.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to link teams channel with communication site ?

No, there is no such option at the moment, and I don't think Microsoft has any such plans as these sites are for a different purpose.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/team-site-or-communication-site

You can add library tab from this site.